# C# Complex INSERT INTO DB

Tags: c#, t-sql

I am pulling my hair out over this one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have three Tables:

```
zaccusr(table)
---------
USRKEY
USRNAME

roleusers (table)
----------
USRKEY
ROLEKEY

acessroles (table)
----------
ROLEKEY
ADDBY
ADDDTTM
MODBY
MODDTTM
ROLEDESC
ROLENAME
```

I need to update the acessroles table based on the the usrname from the zaccusr table.
This database is internal. Even still, I plan to parameritize the variables, but am just trying to get it to work right now. Specifically, I am trying to write a query that I can use in c sharp to iterate through and insert many records.

With that stated, I have tried to use the following query and every variation of it that I can find or think of. Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

```
USE PREPROD
INSERT INTO CORE_ACCESSCONTROL.ACCESSROLES 
(ADDBY,ADDDTTM,MODBY,MODDTTM,ROLEDESC,ROLEKEY,ROLENAME) VALUES 
('SHAGGY','','SHAGGY','','','','AdvancedAssetMgmt') 
select ROLEKEY FROM CORE_ACCESSCONTROL.ROLEUSERS ru
JOIN CORE_ACCESSCONTROL.ZACCUSR zu on ru.USRKEY=zu.USRKEY
WHERE zu.USRNAME ='SCOOBY'
```

Comment: can you please put the C# code up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work..

```
USE PREPROD
INSERT INTO CORE_ACCESSCONTROL.ACCESSROLES 
(ADDBY,ADDDTTM,MODBY,MODDTTM,ROLEDESC,ROLEKEY,ROLENAME) VALUES 
(
'SHAGGY',
'',
'SHAGGY','
',
'',
(select top 1 ROLEKEY FROM CORE_ACCESSCONTROL.ROLEUSERS ru
JOIN CORE_ACCESSCONTROL.ZACCUSR zu on ru.USRKEY=zu.USRKEY
WHERE zu.USRNAME ='SCOOBY'),
'AdvancedAssetMgmt')
```